# Adding body class in author page for custom role

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, body-class

I am trying to add a unique body class using `body_class` filter if the role is a custom one via my plugin. I have a custom role called trip_vendor and the url for its profile page is [abc.com/operator/tripvendor](http://#). Now, I want to add a custom body class if this url is visited. I have over-ridden the author.php from my plugin because the layout needs to be different. My code works in local but fails on live server. Body class as of the live server when the above url visited is ***hfeed full-width***

Below is my code:

```
function vendor_body_class( $classes ) {
        global $post;
        $author = get_queried_object();
        if( is_author() )
        {
            if( end( $author->roles ) == 'trip_vendor' ){
               $classes[] = 'trip-vendor'; 
            }
        } 
        return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'vendor_body_class' );
```

This is how the author template is over-ridden from plugin:

```
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) );
if( is_object($author) )
{
   $role = $author->roles[0];
   if( is_author() )
   {
                if( 'trip_vendor' === $role )
                {
                    if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'author.php' ) ) ) {
                        $template_path = $theme_file;
                    } else {
                        $template_path = WP_TRAVEL_ENGINE_VENDOR_BASE_PATH . '/public/vendor-templates/profile/author.php';
                    }
                }
                return $template_path;
   }


}
```

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: Do you use the same theme on both sites?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Yes both themes are same. The author template is over-ridden from my plugin.

Comment: Try with `in_array()` instead of `end()`? `in_array( 'trip_vendor', $author->roles )`. And maybe on the live server, the `vendor_body_class()` is not being called? A simple `echo 'vendor_body_class';` in that function could confirm that.